# Setting up per-user landing pages in React using dynamic routing

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, url, user-profile, dynamic-routing

I want every user to have a page like: mywebsite.com/username that displays their bio and profile picture.

**How would this be achievable in React?**

My thought process was use dynamic routing and set up a component that pulls the information (bio, profile picture) from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the package `react-router`.

Docs: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Since the username would be unique, you can fetch data from a backend using the username as an unique ID. Fetch the data when the page is loaded. You can take the username from the URL by using `useParams()` hook. Docs: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams